# Extra Character After Form Submition

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is a part of my function that creates selectbox and put the index to each option value. the first textbox gets the count of children based on plus and minus this value changes. if there are a child afterthat i get the age of each children. my problem happens after submit the form i get the value of each age of children. but it shows two commas between each value. 
for example :

> 5,,5,,8

first is age of first childeren , second is age of second children and third for the third age.
this problem happens in action page.
the correct sample should be like this:

> 5,5,8
>
> Note : i have to keep commas just remove extra commas between them

what should I do to solve this problem with extra comma ?
here is my snippet :

```js
$(function() {

  var createChildDropdown = function(i) {
    var $childDropdown = $('<div />', {
      'class': 'childs'
    });
    $childDropdown.append($('<label />', {
      'for': 'childDropdown-' + i
    }).text('Child age ' + i));
    $childDropdown.append($('<select />', {
      'name': 'childDropdown'
    }));
        var options = [' 1 years old', '2 years old', '3 years old'];
    options.forEach(function(option, index) {
   $childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value', `,${index}`));


    });
        return $childDropdown;
  };
    var destroyChildDropdown = function($el, i) {
    $el.find('div.childs').get(i).remove();
  };

  $(".button-click-child a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal + 1 : (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal - 1 : 0;
    var total_value = "";
 if(newVal >= 5) return; 
    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

    $(".cat_textbox").each(function() {
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
    });

    if (oldVal < newVal) {
      $('.childDropdowns').append(createChildDropdown(newVal));
    } else if (oldVal > newVal) {
      destroyChildDropdown($('.childDropdowns'), newVal);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="http://www.fardadtour.com/roundtrip_search.bc">
<input type="text" class="cat_textbox" name="child"  value="0" />

 <ul class="button-group button-click-child">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="hide">+</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ><span class="hide">-</span></a></li>
  </ul>
      <div class="childDropdowns"></div>
  <button type="submit">SEND</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Is this all your code? Where do you know the output?

Comment: @Jackowski output is in the action page and in that page i get dinamically value of select by their names.

Comment: Show that page please.

Comment: @Jackowski how can i show an external page in snippet? in that page i just get the value of form .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value', `,${index}`));
```

You are appending the `index` value with a comma. Correct this with:

```
$childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value', index));
```

Comment: @Andreas you are correct. Thx for pointing out.

Comment: your code destroy all the commas but i want to keep them ,and i  want just to remove the extra comma